# How to manipulate two possible arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I use my custom script `ccc` to compile `.c` files like this:

`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wshadow -g -o "${1%%.c}.out" -lm "$1"`

Basically I use `ccc main.c` and then `main.out` comes out. Now I also want to compile `.cpp` files using the very same script. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "*.cpp" ]; then
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wshadow -g -o "${1%%.cpp}.out" -lm "$1"
    echo "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wshadow -g -o ${1%%}.out -lm $1"
elif [ "$1" == "*.c" ]; then
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wshadow -g -o "${1%%.c}.out" -lm "$1"
    echo "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wshadow -g -o ${1%%}.out -lm $1"
else
    echo "Error - file does not exist or wrong type"
fi
```

However, now both `.cpp` and `.c` files fail to compile and my errmsg gets echoed. What was my mistake?

Comment: You should really be using `make` for this...

Comment: I'm not familiar with `make` so much but wouldn't I have to create a makefile for every single project then?

Comment: Yes, but: 1) a makefile can include other makefiles, 2) makefile give rules (such as how to get from .cpp to .o, often common to many projects) and dependencies (which could be the only thing you have to write, even if make can often discover the dependencies. `make` has been the build tool of choice for over 40 years to C/C++ developers. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) gives you a pretty good idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if tests are not checking for *.c and *.cpp files, they are checking whether the argument is literally "*.cpp" or "*.c".

Try this to see your conditions triggered:
`ccc "*.cpp"`
`ccc "*.c"`

Based on [this post](https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/bash-string-ends-with/), I see you can get the behavior you want by removing the quotes around the "*.cpp" and adding an extra pair of brackets:
`if [[ "$1" == *.cpp ]]; then`

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operators aren't globbing the way you think they are globbing.

When you check for `=="*.c"` or `=="*.cpp"` it is checking to see if it matches that actual string.

What you want is the regular expression comparison.

`if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then`

For the actual regular expression, the character `^` indicates "starts with" and `$` indicates "ends wtih", so

`if [[ $1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.cpp$ ]]; then`

may be a good start for checking for cpp files and

`if [[ $1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.c$ ]]; then`

for c files.

The one skill I strongly recommend to anyone who is a sysadmin (esp. on a *nix system) or does any kind of scripting/programming/development is to learn to use regular expressions.  There are quite few tutorials and cheat-sheets out there, here's the first one in my collection of bookmarks - https://www.maketecheasier.com/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/